# How to insert an object to an object in Mongodb

Tags: python, database, mongodb, object, pymongo

So I have been searching for 2 weeks to find an answer to this question, but seems like it is impossible or I don't know it.
For example, as you know, in JSON you can do something like this (Mentioning streamers part which you can add as many objects as you want to another object.):

```
data = {
    "name": "amirreza",
    "age": 24,
    "streamers": {
        "mine": False, "snipe": True
    }
}
```

Before this, I tried using $set, but it doesn't work as I want, it just replace the last object in the list:

```
list = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]
for i in list:
    s = status.find_one({"_id": 1})
    s2 = s["streamers"]
    if i in s2:
        print("y")
    elif not i in s2:
        status.update_one({"_id": 1}, {"$set": {"streamers": {i: False}}})
```

Now the thing that i want here is

```
data = {
    "name": "amirreza",
    "age": 24,
    "streamers": {
        "test1": False, "test2": False, "test3": False, "test4": False
    }
}
```

But it gives this:

```
data = {
    "name": "amirreza",
    "age": 24,
    "streamers": {
        "test4": False
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`status.update_one({"_id": 1}, {"$set": {"streamers": {i: False}}})` shouldn't be in the loop. By looping through `s2` you are updating `s2` for every iteration, so to visualize, first iteration sets `s2` to `"streamers": { "test1": False}`, second sets `s2` to `"streamers": { "test2": False}`, and so on..., until you reach the end of your list, and the last iteration sets `s2` to `"streamers": { "test4": False}`, you get that result because that's how $set operator works, it updates the whole object.

You are close to the solution. You should simply construct an object by looping through `s2`, and in the end, after you have made the object, you are out of the for loop, you call `status.update_one({"_id": 1}, {"$set": {"streamers": YOUR_OBJECT}})`. That way you update `status` with *all* the streamers, rather than each streamer separately.

Comment: Thanks!, It worked, but there is still one problem, I don't want to update whole "streamers" every time, I just want to add them if they are not in the dictionary.

Comment: You could do that with Python too. `if key not in d:`

Comment: I did, but I don't want to erase previous data, I just want to add new ones. (Because it repeats every 60 seconds)